# Can't download package of Bloc Pattern in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

I want to import `bloc_pattern: ^2.3.5` library at my pubspec.yaml file in my flutter project. I have written it in yaml file, ran pub get command successfully,but for some reason, its package don't get show in the dart packages, which causes redline under the `import 'package:bloc_pattern/bloc_pattern.dart';` I have used these commands already `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` but still the red line persist. I have also tried to change the version of library but can't use the latest library of null-safety because currently I am using `flutter version 1.22.4`. Help please!

Comment: close and open your editor

Comment: if you don't have requirement for specific version, don't specific version, at all use only like this bloc_pattern: ,   it will automatically installs appropriate plugin version.

Comment: Still the issue persist. Really very strange and frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Restart your ide.
Run flutter clean
Run flutter pub get

Comment: I have done this several times but the issue persists.

Comment: Okay, can please tell me exact error Lister in problem tab of dart analysis.